# Как создать такой график?

Tags: c#

[image: График забронированных мест]

Пишу программу автоматизации отеля.Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать подобный график!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Пишу программу автоматизации отеля.Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать подобный график!

Знаком с темой гостиничной шахматки не по наслышке. Могу порекомендовать следующее:

1. **Диаграмма Ганта (Gantt chart)**

Этот тип диаграмм весьма удобен для демонстрации событий/действий, разворачивающихся во времени. Я не вспомню какой именно контрол использовал (какую-то демо-версию), но он был крайне неудобен.

Есть один плюс - некоторая интерактивность - вы не только визуалиализируете шахматку, но и можете редактировать бронирования/поселения прямо в графике.

[image: gantt chart]

Местами не очень удобно, поскольку диаграммы Ганта больше подходят для визуализации "проектов".

2. **Столбчатая диаграмма (Bar chart)**

В принципе подходящий варант - повёрнутая на бок столбчатая диаграмма (stacked bar chart). По сравнению диаграммой Ганта, работает быстрее, глюков меньше, но и функций меньше.

Выглядит примерно так:
[image: chart sample]

Придётся очень гибко создавать серии и категории (для каждой комнаты и постояльца), чтобы добиться желаемого результата.

3. **Самодельный контрол**

Ну тут всё что душа пожелает. Но кодить придётся много. Особое внимание следует уделить производительности того что получится.

4. **Табличный документ**

Можно использовать как контролы типа DataGrid, так и типа ExcelGrid.

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ!